# Clipping polygons to existing plotting area

Tags: r, clip, sp, rgeos

I have an existing plotting area onto which I want to add some polygons.

In order to be sure the polygons' labels are displayed within the plotting area, I'd like to clip the polygons to this area so that the `coordinates` of the resulting object are guaranteed to be within the existing area:

```
set.seed(30482)
x = runif(20)
y = runif(20)

base_poly = cbind(c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  c(0, 1, 1, 0))
shift = .5*expand.grid(c(-1, 1), c(-1, 1))
SP = SpatialPolygons(
  lapply(1:4, function(ii) 
    Polygons(
      list(Polygon(
        sweep(base_poly, 2L, unlist(shift[ii, ]), '-')
      )), 
      ID = sprintf('Polygon %d', ii)
    ))
)

plot(x, y)
plot(SP, add = TRUE)
text(coordinates(SP), labels = sapply(SP@polygons, slot, 'ID'))
```

[image: baseline]

As you can see, the centroids of the `SP` polygons lie outside the plotting area, so they're not really showing up in the plot (in this example, I could use `xpd = TRUE` to some success but this is not true in general).

My fix is to clip `SP` to the plotting area like so:

```
plot(x, y)
pu = par('usr')
SP = gIntersection(
  SP,
  SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(
    list(Polygon(cbind(pu[rep(1:2, each = 2L)], pu[c(3:4, 4:3)]))), 
    ID = '0'
  )), proj4string = SP@proj4string),
  byid = TRUE,
  id = sapply(SP@polygons, slot, 'ID')
)

plot(SP, add = TRUE)
text(coordinates(SP), labels = sapply(SP@polygons, slot, 'ID'))
```

[image: expected output]

Is this the canonical approach to this? The construction of the plotting area as a `SpatialPolygons` object seems pretty hack-y, am I missing some convenience functions for accomplishing this without as much manual input?